# How to produce a quicktime .mov from .iff files?

Tags: windows-7, file-conversion, video-editing

I have a series of Maya .iff files and would like to mash them into a .mov - the caveat of course is that I'd like to use something free (for now). I'm sure QuickTime Pro is easy & high quality, but I'm trying to keep the budget low until I can start getting paid for this.

I don't mind if it's not the easiest thing to use, and it doesn't have to be the world's best quality. I figure that'll come once I shell out some cash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried VLC?  It supports many different formats and can be used to convert formats:

http://www.videolan.org/

Comment: Sadly, VLC doesn't produce quicktime files. Looks like this will be at least a 2 part process.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose the pictures, slideshow, or album you want to include in your movie.
2. Select "File" then "Export"
3. Based on the option you chose in Step 1, you can do one of the following:

   a) If you chose "Slideshow" - name your movie, save it to a file that is easily accessible, determine the size, then click "Export."

   b) If you chose "Individual Photos", or an "Album" - at the top you will see "Export Photos"; from there select the "QuickTime" button, then proceed to the following steps.

Comment: I may have been unclear, I don't actually have Quicktime pro. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering how to do this with .iff files, it can be done using VirtualDub. On the VirtualDub 'Open Video' dialog, make sure that the 'Automatically load linked segments' checkbox is checked, navigate to and click on the first file in the sequence, then click open.

The video can then be saved as an .avi file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Maya, it comes with a utility program called Fcheck that can open a sequence of Maya iff files and save them as a QuickTime movie. You need to have a numbered sequence of files for it to work.

1) Go to the Applications > Autodesk > Maya folder and open the  Fcheck program.

2) In Fcheck, go to File > Open sequence

3) Navigate to where you have the series of iff files and select the first file in the sequence. The entire sequence will open in Fcheck and play in a loop, very fast. Don't bother to try to change it with the controls - they don't really work anymore, and it won't affect the final movie speed.

4) While it's playing, go to File > Save as movie and follow the prompts to save a QuickTime movie.